# Application insights - Live metrics

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

We have wired up Azure application insights instance to Azure service fabric which is hosting .net core 2.1 applications. As expected Azure service fabric related telemetry data pumped in to target application insights instance but CPU & memory usage related metrics are not showing up (screenshot attached) why? How to overcome the issue to monitor or observe CPU & memory related metrics on each service fabric node using "Live stream" window?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please share how you have configured App Insights? Do you have Windows Azure Diagnostics enable on your cluster? You may need to add some custom code to your setup to pass along the desired info. There's an example of this here: https://github.com/Expecho/Azure-Service-Fabric-Logging-And-Monitoring

Comment: But using KQL we can able to query CPU & memory usage related metrics from app-insights db. Only on 'Live Metrics' CPU & memory usage related details not shown up as highlighted on the attached screenshot.

Comment: The data for live metrics and the logs are on completely separate channels. Depending on the environment, you can see the results you are getting where performance counters in one channel is not being sent to the other. There are additional libraries for Service Fabric to help get the telemetry correct. While live stream is enabled by default, depending on the applications you are running, you may need to manually setup the live stream in your App Insights configuration. https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-ServiceFabric

Comment: If "The data for live metrics and the logs are on completely separate channels." than at present how come Live metrics shows up other metrics like request rate, request duration WITHOUT including any Live metrics related additional libraries/config ? But not just showing up CPU/Memory.

Comment: I've reached out to the product team to help troubleshooting. Can you check the App Insights SDK version for me?

Comment: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.ServiceFabric.Native" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Diagnostics.Internal" Version="4.1.417" />

Comment: I apologize for the delay. There should be other app insights packages that than the Service Fabric one or you wouldn't be getting live metrics at all. Do you have version numbers for them as well?

Comment: @SamaraSoucy-MSFT - added the screenshot of the app insights related nuget package added to my project apart from that no other app insights related  nuget package used at present in my project

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you don't have Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore installed on any of the apps pushing data to that workspace? The ServiceFabric.Native fabric by itself shouldn't be able to push any live metrics by itself.

Comment: No. I have attached the screenshot of the SDKs incorporated in the Azure Service Fabric service project, nothing else has been installed in the project we are talking about. Can you tell me what is missing which is supposed to be? so that I can included & can able to absorb CPU & memory usage on Azure Application Insights - Live Metrics window.

Comment: Depends on the type of service. For console apps, 
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService. For web apps Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore. The Service Fabric helps to support those packages.